# Accessing the nth element of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, search, modulus

Given a number n and a matrix, represented as an array of arrays. How would you find the nth element? The answer I am looking should involve the modulus operation and not use standard library functions.

So for example n = 7 and the matrix:

```
[
[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4],
[a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8],
[a_9,a_10,a_11,a_12]
]
```

Comment: What is the output in your example?

Comment: theres no output, its a theoretical question

Comment: well it would be $a_7$

Comment: Are the rows of your *array of arrays* always going to be of equal length?

Comment: yes they will be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we use zero-based indexing to make things simpler. So, if we want the 7th element, we use `n=6`.

```
rowIndex = n / rowLength
columnIndex = n % rowLength
answer = array[rowIndex][columnIndex]
```

Comment: possibly that / should be // or cast to an int

Comment: The division should be integer-based (such that disregards any non-zero remainder), yes. For example: `3 / 4 = 0`, `6 / 4 = 1`.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this would help.

```
############# Inputs ################

matrix = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6]]
## n is the element we need to find 
n = 16

########## Search Matrix element Logic ###########

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[1])):
        if matrix[i][j] == n:
            print('row:',i,' column:',j)
            break;

        elif ( (j == len(matrix[1])-1)  and (i== len(matrix)-1) ):
            print("element not found")
```

Comment: The OP was not searching the matrix for *value* `n` but for the element at *index* `n`.